# MAC Address of other wifi device in a wifi network

Tags: c, visual-c++, ip-address, mac-address

Is it possible to find the MAC address of all other wifi enabled device in a wifi network programmatically by using C or C++, if so then please tell me the way or direction, how can i do that Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in same LAN next to your device (no router/switch in the middle, The scope of ARP is link-layer.) you should use sending [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) packets to devices.

> Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) is a telecommunications protocol
>   used for resolution of network layer addresses into link layer
>   addresses.

To send ARPs you can use [Pcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) or [SendARP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).